# SQLite commands not recognized when running through Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm trying to use Mybatis to run a SQL script to initialize a database as shown [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-sql-script-using-jdbc) but get an `SQLException` saying "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver". I've checked that my SQL statement is valid and it works on the very same database via both the console interface and Java's `PreparedStatement`.

Here's my initialization class along with the code that successfully creates the table commented out:

```
public void init() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("db_init.sql");

        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
            sr.runScript(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            //PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (testColumn TEXT);");
            //stmt.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The SQL contained in `db_init.sql` is exactly the same as in the commented `conn.prepareStatement()` call.

And here is the console output this generates:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (
  testColumn TEXT
)

Error executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (
  testColumn TEXT
)
.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.RuntimeSqlException: Error executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (
  testColumn TEXT
)
.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
        at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:150)
        at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:110)
        at fi.basse.shamery.db.Database.init(Database.java:60)
        at fi.basse.shamery.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.unused(JDBC3Statement.java:387)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.setEscapeProcessing(JDBC3Statement.java:382)
        at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeStatement(ScriptRunner.java:230)
        at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.handleLine(ScriptRunner.java:210)
        at org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner.executeLineByLine(ScriptRunner.java:143)
        ... 3 more
```

Is there a way to get `ScriptRunner.runScript()` working or do I have to parse and execute the statements in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the escape processing that is [not implemented](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/aab7a7218f84d63a578d16ca8bdd1410c5a1ded6/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3Statement.java#L382) by the driver.
Disabling escape processing should work.

```java
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
sr.setEscapeProcessing(false);
sr.runScript(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```